# arabic words does not show correctly

Tags: microsoft-excel, language, arabic

I have some words which are not the same in edit mode (upper view) and cell view in excel. I have Arabic language proofing support installed already.

[Video](https://imgur.com/uiNGVuu)

Please see the video. Any suggestions ?

Thanks for help...

Comment: Is that Microsoft Excel? You need to change the text direction I think. https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel/type-arabic-text-and-numbers-in-excel-sheet/m-p/3828406

Comment: @Gantendo yes, excel , i have already changed it, no effect...

Comment: Sadly there is no Arabic Stack Exchange currently https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283101/arabic-stack-exchange

Comment: Can you give more information? Also, pictures are better than video on this site because we can see embedded pictures here, and videos mean we have to leave this site. Also, Excel data is mostly static. What version(s) of Excel? What words? Do any/all words in this language do this?

Comment: @music2myear my word was **اﻧﺒﻮب 8 اﻧﺞ PVC ﺑﯿﻦ ﻣﻨﮭﻮل اﻟﺘﺠﻤﯿﻊ  وﺧﺰان اﻟﺘﻌﻔﯿﻦ** but when I copy the same word from previous excel file, it was fine but when I try to write by myself, it does not show the correct word.